# Testing Navigation from ActionBar menu

Tags: android, android-testing, android-navigation, android-instrumentation

I am trying to write a test for a menu item. The idea is to click on the menu item and verify that the NavController is set to the correct destination:

```
public class NavigationTest {
    @Test
    public void clickOnSearchMenuNavigatesToFilter() {
        TestNavHostController navController = new TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());
        ActivityScenario<MainActivity> listScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class);
        listScenario.onActivity(activity -> {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph);
            Navigation.setViewNavController(activity.requireViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment), navController);
        });
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.filter_menu)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentDestination()).getId()).isEqualTo(R.id.filter_cards);
    }
}
```

This test fails with

> expected: 2131296468
>
> but was : 2131296378

`2131296378` is the id for the initial fragment in the `NavController`. What is wrong with my test? My initial thinking is that I am not injecting the `TestNavHostController` correctly, but debugging verified that the activity sees it as I expect:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint here, I confirm that `navController` is an instance of `TestNavHostController`.

For completeness, here's my `nav_graph.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/card_list">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/card_list"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardList"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/card_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_details"
            app:destination="@id/card_details" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_filter"
            app:destination="@id/filter_cards" />
        <argument
            android:name="filterParams"
            app:argType="android.os.Bundle"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.About"
        android:label="@string/about_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/card_details"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.BaseballCardDetails"
        android:label="@string/card_details_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/card_details">
        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="long" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/filter_cards"
        android:name="bbct.android.common.fragment.FilterCards"
        android:label="@string/filter_cards_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/filter_cards">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_list"
            app:destination="@id/card_list" />
    </fragment>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        app:destination="@id/about" />
</navigation>
```

Any ideas what I am missing or anything I can try to troubleshoot this test?

**Addendum:**

Note that my test here uses an `ActivityScenario` instead of a `FragmentScenario` as in the [example from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing). I realize this might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I use a `ActivityScenario` in this test because I need to click on a `MenuItem` in the toolbar which is hosted in the `Activity`. In my previous attempts using a `FragmentScenario`, the toolbar wasn't rendered. I'm open to suggestions that use a different approach to the test I'm trying to write.

Comment: Hello, shouldn't `R.id.filter_menu` & `R.id.filter_cards` be the same id in order to make the navigation works? can you plz advise.. If they differ then the `2131296378` is the right thing I guess

Comment: Just tested it, with the same Ids and it worked; this could be the cause

Comment: @Zain Thanks for looking at this. To clarify, `R.id.filter_menu` is the id of the `MenuItem` in the UI while `R.id.filter_cards` is the id of `FilterCards` fragment in the nav graph. I don't think these ids should be the same since they refer to different elements of the UI. The test clicks on the menu item to navigate to the fragment.

Comment: @Zain `2131296378` is the value of `R.id.card_list`, so shouldn't be correct after navigating to `FilterCards`.

Comment: Could you provide how the navigation looks like from card_list to filter_cards.. do you use the `action_filter` action programmatically on this?

Comment: @Zain What do you mean by "how the navigation looks like from card_list to filter_cards"? I assume you don't mean the navgraph since I posted it in the question.  The view `R.id.filter_menu` which the test clicks on is a menu item in the action bar. That's why I show `onOptionsItemSelected()` for handling menu item clicks. Is there something else you want other than those?

Comment: Exactly, how do you handle the the menu id `R.id.filter_menu` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` .. I mean do you do something like `navController.navigate(R.id.action_filter)`?

Comment: Sorry, just saw that `onOptionsItemSelected`  included; so, just not sure how the navigation could happen in your case; what is the correlation between clicking on the this particular `ActionBar` menu item `R.id.filter_menu` and to go to `filter_cards` destination fragment.. AFAIK this should work by having the same id of the menu item & the destination fragment (in navGraph)

Comment: Can you pls have a look at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer).. In particular `If the id of the MenuItem matches the id of the destination, the NavController can then navigate to that destination.`

Comment: @Zain Will you please post an answer? That change appears to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tie navigation destinations to menu items, the IDs of both need to match [as per documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer):

> If the id of the MenuItem matches the id of the destination, the NavController can then navigate to that destination.

This is not exclusive to `ActionBar` menu, but also to other types of menus like Navigation Drawer & `BottomNavigationView` menus.

Without that in place, the navigation won't occur, and the test will fail because the current destination stays unchanged.

To fix this, both `R.id.filter_menu` & `R.id.filter_cards` need to be matched in menu & `navGraph` XML files, and also in the test, assuming both are `filter_cards`, then  `R.id.filter_menu` needs to be changed in the menu file and in the test to be `R.id.filter_cards`:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.filter_cards)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

Comment: The strange thing is that the correct fragment was loaded after clicking on the menuu, but the state of the `NavController` doesn't seem to update.